# Edit group permissions for members - Telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

how to change the group permissions in telethon? this permissions will applied to any new member joined the group.

you can find this settings in telegram app, in manage group => Permissions.

screenshot : [what-can-members-of-this-group-do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dP1ty.png)

I found in telethon doc `EditAdminRequest` but this take a user as parameter, I need to set the permissions for all users that will join the group. (as you can see in the screenshot in telegram app they write : What can members of this group do?).

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.chats.ChatMethods.edit_permissions

edit_permissions() while leaving `user` empty does this